# Drupal Media + Wysiwyg (+CKEditor) inserting image issues

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg, media

I'm using Media with CKEditor through Wysiwyg on Drupal 7.  When I insert an image, it looks great in the editor:

[image: lookin good]

However, when I click "save", the rendered page looks like this:

[image: not so good]

What is happening here?  How do I fix it so that the image shows on the page like it is in the editor?

(I'm asking this question here and not on the Drupal StackExchange site because it might be an issue with CKEditor, which is not drupal-specific)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one got me the other day too, you need to go to `admin/config/content/formats/full_html`, select the checkbox that says 'Converts Media tags to Markup', then the 'Save Configuration' button...all will be well!

**EDIT**

Actually this isn't necessarily limited to the Full HTML filter (it looks from your image that you're using filtered HTML), but go to `admin/config/content/formats`, then select each filter you want to enable media markup for and perform the same action.

Comment: Is there a way to force CKEditor to put HTML tags instead of Media tags?

Comment: Without writing a custom ckeditor plugin to do the job @maciek, I doubt it. It uses the token system, and those square-bracketed tags are converted to HTML before render, based on other contextual information available from the entity

Comment: @Clive is it possible that in older versions of CKEditor it was inserting HTML instead of those Media tags?